# Stablist / easiest to maintain free OS to run SAMBA 4, PostgreSQL, mod_perl2 on?

Tags: postgresql, samba, operating-system, mod-perl

This is just for a 20-client network of XP Pro machines: a file/print share server, possibly a domain controller unless I can get by without it, and a db and intranet app host.  I need to be able to administer it remotely; GUI or CLI is fine.  What will bring the least headache / widest support (e.g. highest likelyhood of Perl modules working, things not breaking after an OS update, etc.) on a zero budget?

Comment: Asking for the "most stable" or "easiest to maintain" OS is like asking for the "best car" - 10 people will give you 10 different answers (and if they're all in the same room when you ask there's a really good chance a fight will break out!) -- this is part of why [product and service recommendations are off topic on Stack Exchange sites](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) :-)

Answer (score 1):

'The one you know best.'

My suggestion would be to play with a few and decide which one you're most comfortable with.  There are many answers to this question, all of them subjective.

Comment: Sure, but experience with Perl module support and things breaking can include objective data.  Nonetheless this is a wise answer.